# Performance gains with null rather than default values?

Tags: java, performance, optimization, memory

They say premature optimisation is the root of all evil, but here goes...

We have a high-performance application; an in-memory cache backed by Java on the server side and what needs to be a very snappy C# GUI on the client side.

I note that currently the objects we are using in the cache have default values - e.g. initialising Strings by default to "" and Dates to 1/1/1999 rather than leaving them null.

Now I might be being very finicky here, but doesn't this add a tiny bit more space per object (both in the cache and when the object gets serialized) than it would otherwise have if it were null?

Just wondering what sort of improvement (if any) would be gained when our volumes of objects start getting quite high...

Cheers,
Dave.

Comment: @f1dave: wow...  High performance application and you're storing dates in objects?  A point in time should be stored in a primitive (say a Java *long*), as (milli)seconds elapsed since the epoch.  This is nearly always true, especially so if performance is a concern.  The only moment where you need to "format" that point in time as a date is when some user wants to read it in a user-friendly way (say in its own timezone etc.).

Comment: @Anon. I don't see how that at all is related to the performance question.

Comment: @Kaj - the OP asked about "a tiny bit more space," not CPU.

Comment: And the use of default values (aka "null object pattern") is typically to prevent NPEs.

Comment: Oh look, for sure I'd be concerned about NPEs. But I'm putting on my black hat for a moment (dumb hat, whatever). 

@SyntaxT3rr0r - The cache stores objects. The objects themselves have attributes which are as basic as can be, mostly primitives. They do however use java.util.Date.

Comment: What happens if you need to store 1/1/1999 as a valid date? Using special values instead of null is a bad idea.

Comment: @Anon. He also said that he's sending the instances to the client and that he is concerned about the performance impact of sending object with default values. Buying more RAM will not answer/solve that problem.

Comment: @Kaj - true, but I would consider marginal network bandwidth for empty strings to be even less of a "problem." than RAM. And the time to process those empty strings, versus the lag in actually sending them over the network ... :shrug:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Premature optimization is certainly evil.

But thinking about the performance characteristics of your application and appropriate designs strategies to optimise for performance is perfectly reasonable if performance is a key requirement of the application :-)

A few relevant points:

- There are some (slight) **performance benefits from using null** rather than a default value. It's easier for the native code to check for a null value than it is to dereference an object reference and examine the value of that object. You probably won't notice this if everything is in L1 cache, but if this causes cache misses in a high-performance application it could become painful.
- There is some extra memory overhead but it probably doesn't matter much - assuming you re-use the same default value objects many times (i.e. many keys point to the same value) then there won't be many extra object instances overall.
- If your default vales are **immutable, singleton objects** then it helps enormously, for three reasons:

  - You only need one copy of the immutable object, rather than different instances of "" (String.intern() helps here!)
  - A single object used many times is much more likely to be cached efficiently
  - You can use reference equality (value == DEFAULT_SINGLETON) to test for the default value, which avoid the need for a pointer dereference when DEFAULT_SINGLETON is a static final value.
- If you do use immutable singleton default values, be very careful not to get any other instances of the same value mixed in. This can happen e.g. when deserializing objects - you need to use readResolve() etc. to ensure you get the right singleton value in place.

In my opinion, you should probably prefer nulls for default values.

- It's marginally faster and uses less memory
- It is more likely to help you detect a logic error (via a loud NullPointerException rather than causing a difficult-to-track bug with a default value being used in place of a real value)

Comment: Cheers mikera. Yeah, looks like we are pretty consistent in using immutable, singleton objects as you say. And what do you know, the guy who wrote the code originally is the one asking me to investigate nulls ;)